# adding a field name as a method parameter

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing form where I want to detect edited field data so I can update the data via a web service. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this as there are a plethora of medium to complex code examples for this, most of which are over my head! However, I think I found a simple solution that will fit my needs and I wanted to run it by the group for input / suggestions. FYI: it may not matter but know that I am using NetBeans so things like listeners are auto-coded by the app.

Step 1: When I load the form, I am saving all the data to a Class array so I know the starting point of the each field. Here is the code for that load:

```
public void coSetSearchDetail(String coDetail){ 
    String[] text; 
    System.out.println("SingleCO Result: "+ coDetail); 
    text = coDetail.split("\\|"); 
    txtName_CoDetail.setText(text[1]); 
    txtAddr_CoDetail.setText(text[2]);
    txtAddr2_CoDetail.setText(text[3]);
    txtCity_CoDetail.setText(text[4]);
    txtState_CoDetail.setText(text[5]);
    txtZip_CoDetail.setText(text[6]);

    stringarrayCoDetails[0] = text[0];
    stringarrayCoDetails[1] = text[1];
    stringarrayCoDetails[2] = text[2];
    stringarrayCoDetails[3] = text[3];
    stringarrayCoDetails[4] = text[4];
    stringarrayCoDetails[5] = text[5];
    stringarrayCoDetails[6] = text[6];
    java.awt.CardLayout card = (java.awt.CardLayout)pnlMain.getLayout();
    card.show(pnlMain, "pnlCoDetail");
}
```

Step 2: I created a Lost Focus event listener for one field and am testing the current value of the field against the array:

```
private void txtName_CoDetailFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt)     {                                           

    if (!(txtName_CoDetail.getText().equals(stringarrayCoDetails[1]))){
        createEditBorder();
    }

}                                          

private void createEditBorder (){
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2);
    txtName_CoDetail.setBorder(border);
}
```

Besides the general question of "is this an OK approach?", I would like to be able to pass the field name to the `createEditBorder` method so the listener for each data field can call it and I have one method for "edited text" formatting.

Comment: adding a field name as a method parameter --> directly not possible, but there are (I think that in every Swing APis) setName, get/putClientProperty, etc., maybe overloading with success, nobody knows, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for Swing GUi in local variables

Comment: @mKorbel, I'm not clear what you are suggesting to look for?

Comment: I'm sure that :-) an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for Swing GUi in local variables

Comment: Ok...I had to look up SSCCE/MCVE... I will work on a compilable example, however, just to be clear it works and I am not getting an error.  I'm just trying to figure out how to not hardcode the textfield name.  Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want createEditBorder() to deal with any of your text fields. If so, I'd do this. Have createEditBorder() take a JTextField (I assume txtName_CoDetail et. al. are that type) as an input parameter. You can then call .setBorder for that text field. As to how to pass the text field in, I'm assuming (and please check me on this) that your focus event contains the source of the event, i.e. the text field. So if you add txtName_CoDetailFocusLost as a focus listener to all of your text fields, that should work.

Comment: @swingMan: I added evt.getSource() to the Focuslost listener, which returns a generic Object.  Passing this to createEditBorder() as a param, I don't have the full text field method list (like setBorder() ).  Am I understanding you correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: The way you have this set up you could pass the arrays and an index into your listener constructor and compare it with evt.getSource().getText ()

Comment: @creed....you'll have to cast the Object to a text field. Forgot about that...event source is always an Object, but since you know what control your listener is attached to (make them unique), you can safely cast then get access to the methods you want.

Comment: @swingMan: If I understand you correctly, I need to recast the string as an object to get to the methods, correct?

Comment: @creed You have to cast the object you get from the event source to a text field. Then you have access to the text field methods you want.